# User on SQLAgentOperatorRole unable to edit jobs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent

My Active Directory account is on an AD group that is on msdb's SQLAgentOperatorRole. I'm able to list existing MSSQL Agent jobs, but I can only view their steps and schedules, I'm unable to edit them or create new.

I'm able to create new jobs, but on their step, when I select CmdExec, no proxy is listed.

If I remove this group from SQLAgentOperatorRole, no job is listed anymore.

When I log as `sa` I'm able to edit jobs and proxies are listed.

Am I missing something to be able to manage jobs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent-fixed-database-roles?view=sql-server-ver15. It clearly states what you can do with this role. It does not include privileges to edit a job owned by somebody else, for instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm gonna read it now. If needed I make another question asking how to set it up.